# ¿Cómo poner un botón en el titlebar de un grid en SENCHA TOUCH 2?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

Estoy empezando a utilizar este framework, mi duda es la siguiente.
Acabo de crear un Grid en sencha touch la versión 2.4.2.
El Grid tiene por opción poner el título de titlebar de grid con esta línea

```
title:"titulo",
```

pero yo quisiera ponerle un botón como el que se hace con el siguiente código que utilizo para entrar a otro view.

```
xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Verificar Ruta',
                items:[
                    {
                       text: 'Menu Principal',
                       ui: 'back',
                       handler: function() {
                        //console.log('click');
                            Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);
                            var nextView = Ext.create('BusingChof.view.Inicio');

                            Ext.Viewport.add(nextView);
                            Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(nextView, {type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});
                            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(nextView);
                        }     
                    }
                ]
```

¿Es posible crear un botón asi en un grid directamente?

Answer (score 0):

en el config de tu Grid puedes poner la propiedad titleBar con la configuracion que tu quieras, por ejemplo:

```
config: {
titleBar: {
    title: 'Verificar Ruta',
    items: [{
        text: 'Menu Principal',
        ui: 'back',
        handler: function() {
            //console.log('click');
            Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);
            var nextView = Ext.create('BusingChof.view.Inicio');

            Ext.Viewport.add(nextView);
            Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(nextView, { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' });
            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(nextView);
        }
    }]
}
```

}

Otra recomendacion es que uses una Ext.navigation.View para que el te haga la gestion de los elementos del viewport